# WCF related - System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The message could not be processed

Tags: vb.net, wcf

This is similar to: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/71c31684-1ce7-4fd9-bf24-674e6dc707bf/the-message-could-not-be-processed?forum=wcf

However, I did not forget an entry like that person did yet I still get the same error.

I get:

System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/IBackupServerService/DeleteBySpaceIdProcess' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.

Note: I'm hosting the service from a console app on a server and then calling the service from a web app located on another server.

My client web.config file looks like: (Note: the "IP address" and "userPrincipalName" are both fictitious for this posting.)

```
<!-- Specifies the version of WCF to use. -->
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IBackupServerService"  >
        <security mode="None" />
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://999.999.999.999:8000/Application/BackupServerServiceLibrary/BackupServerService/BackupServerService"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IBackupServerService"
    contract="ServiceReference1.IBackupServerService" name="WSHttpBinding_IBackupServerService">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="AAAAA5-415-B\jbrown" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My service app.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
   </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
     <services>
       <service name="BackupServerServiceLibrary.BackupServerService">
       <host>
         <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress = "/BackupServerServiceLibrary/BackupServerService/" />
         </baseAddresses>
       </host>
       <!-- Service Endpoints -->
       <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        contract="BackupServerServiceLibrary.IBackupServerService"
        bindingConfiguration="NoSecurity">
       <!-- Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced 
       to reflect the identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, 
       WCF will infer an appropriate identity automatically. -->
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
       </endpoint>
       <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
       <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
     </service>
   </services>
   <bindings>
     <wsHttpBinding>
       <binding name="NoSecurity">
         <security mode="None" />
       </binding>
     </wsHttpBinding>
   </bindings>   
   <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior>
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
       </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this would cause the issue, but the `<identity>` nodes are of different types and values across the configuration files. DNS on the service side and UPN on the client side.

Comment: I made them the same earlier and it did not change anything.